# UPDATE INNER JOIN 3 tablas

Tags: sql

Tengo la select es esta

```
SELECT contrato.CodContrato as CodigoContrato, contrato.Descripcion as DescripcionContrato, centro.CodCentroContrato as CodigoCentroContrato, centro.AliasCentro , trabajo.CodRutaMultiempresa as Ruta, trabajo.NumTrabajo as NumeroTrabajo,
CASE WHEN trabajo.Periodicidad = 1 THEN 'Diaria'
WHEN trabajo.Periodicidad = 2 THEN 'Semanal'
WHEN trabajo.Periodicidad = 3 THEN 'Quincenal'
WHEN trabajo.Periodicidad = 4 THEN 'Mensual'
WHEN trabajo.Periodicidad = 5 THEN 'Bimestral'
WHEN trabajo.Periodicidad = 6 THEN 'Trimestral'
WHEN trabajo.Periodicidad = 7 THEN 'Cuatrimestral'
WHEN trabajo.Periodicidad = 8 THEN 'Semestral'
WHEN trabajo.Periodicidad = 9 THEN 'Anual'
ELSE 'No tiene periodicidad'
END as Periodicidad,
trabajo.FechaInicioServicios as InicioTrabajoRuta, trabajo.FechaFinServicios as FinTrabajoRuta, contrato.FechaFin as FechaFinContrato
FROM [Servicios y Mtto_, S_A_$Contrato] contrato
INNER JOIN [Servicios y Mtto_, S_A_$CentroContrato] centro ON contrato.CodContrato = centro.CodContrato
INNER JOIN TrabajoContrato trabajo ON centro.CodCentroContrato = trabajo.CodCentroContrato
WHERE trabajo.CodRutaMultiempresa IN ('SUPER CASH', 'DDD', 'MADRID', 'BARCELONA', 'VALENCIA')
AND trabajo.FechaFinServicios BETWEEN '01/12/2018' AND '31/12/2018'
AND contrato.Estado = '6
```

Me devuelve los datos correctamente

Ahora estoy intentando hacer un UPDATE para el campo trabajo.FechaFinServicios establezca todos los resultados del select anterior a '31/12/2019'

Quito el select y pongo UPDATE pero me da errores, queda así:

```
UPDATE [Servicios y Mtto_, S_A_$Contrato] contrato
INNER JOIN [Servicios y Mtto_, S_A_$CentroContrato] centro ON contrato.CodContrato = centro.CodContrato
INNER JOIN TrabajoContrato trabajo ON centro.CodCentroContrato = trabajo.CodCentroContrato
SET trabajo.FechaFinServicios = '31/12/2019'
WHERE trabajo.CodRutaMultiempresa IN ('SUPER CASH', 'DDD', 'MADRID', 'BARCELONA', 'VALENCIA')
AND trabajo.FechaFinServicios BETWEEN '01/12/2018' AND '31/12/2018'
AND contrato.Estado = '6'
```

Como deberia ser el UPDATE teniendo en cuenta que tengo bien el SELECT?

Comment: ¿Podrías editar la pregunta con la estructura de la base de datos en SQL y algún registro de muestra para hacer comprobaciones (phpMyAdmin, Exportar)? Estaría genial que especificaras en las etiquetas el sistema gestor de bases de datos que utilizas, ¿mysql, sql-server, oracle...?

Answer (score 0):

Prueba con lo siguiente:

```
UPDATE contrato
SET trabajo.FechaFinServicios = '31/12/2019'
FROM [Servicios y Mtto_, S_A_$Contrato] contrato
    INNER JOIN [Servicios y Mtto_, S_A_$CentroContrato] centro ON contrato.CodContrato = centro.CodContrato
    INNER JOIN TrabajoContrato trabajo ON centro.CodCentroContrato = trabajo.CodCentroContrato
    WHERE trabajo.CodRutaMultiempresa IN ('SUPER CASH', 'DDD', 'MADRID', 'BARCELONA', 'VALENCIA')
    AND trabajo.FechaFinServicios BETWEEN '01/12/2018' AND '31/12/2018'
    AND contrato.Estado = '6'
```

Comment: no vale, da errores

Comment: si no cuentas un poco mas de los errores que da, difícilmente puedo seguir ayudando